# Aggregator transformation gives only one row

Tags: informatica-powercenter

In aggregator transformation,I used max function. I am getting single row for each group. But multiple rows have maximum value. How to get the other rows details

Answer (score 0):

In such case you need to calculate the MAX value per group, just as you seem to have done, and then join the result back to the original dataset via `Joiner Transformation` using value and group key as join conditions. As a result you should get all the rows with max value per group.

This should look more or less as depicted below:

```
SRC--SQ--AGG-\
       \      \
        \------JNR--TGT
```

Comment: What should be the condition in joiner,  I have to find max age for each country. So should I use age from source and max(age) from aggregator as joining condition?

Comment: Country name, country code - or whatever indicator you use for the country. You need to use this as you group by county and need to join back the group.

Answer (score 0):

no group by port is defined agg is considering all the record as one group and return the last record.